# how to remove comments in xml without removing its text in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

input file

```
<a>
<b>
<!--<docinfo:topiccodes><docinfo:topiccode>#PA#HKCRP#</docinfo:topiccode>    <docinfo:topiccode>#PA#HKCRPM#</docinfo:topiccode><docinfo:topiccode>#PA#HKDIS#</docinfo:topiccode><docinfo:topiccode>#PA#HKDISM#</docinfo:topiccode><docinfo:topiccode>#PA#CODE#</docinfo:topiccode></docinfo:topiccodes>--> 
</b>
</a>
```

output expexted

```
<a>
<b>
<docinfo:topiccodes><docinfo:topiccode>#PA#HKCRP#</docinfo:topiccode>    <docinfo:topiccode>#PA#HKCRPM#</docinfo:topiccode><docinfo:topiccode>#PA#HKDIS#</docinfo:topiccode><docinfo:topiccode>#PA#HKDISM#</docinfo:topiccode><docinfo:topiccode>#PA#CODE#</docinfo:topiccode></docinfo:topiccodes> 
</b>
</a>
```

xslt written

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*|processing-instruction()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment()">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not working ..i Tried this but its not working for me

Comment: Well, i do not know how you implemented it. But it is working. See here (http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtz)

Comment: ok i was implementing it in my code ,i think my code is having any issue ,other wise its working fine.